# ubuntu php 5.5.38 upgrade to 5.5.9

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, upgrade, php-5.5

This is my first question since registering here at Stack Overflow.

I have installed Linux Mint 18 (Sarah) which runs of the 16.04 base of Ubuntu as I understand it (I am still fairly new to Linux ~1 year experience).

My issue is that I am trying to run the same version of PHP locally as in the production environment. I managed to install php 5.5.38 but the prod environment is running 5.5.9 and I can't find how to do the upgrade.

I have tried updating my repositories and the executing the upgrade command. Nothing. I search online, and nothing.

I am thinking what I have to do is purge/uninstall php completely and add the correct repo? Is this right or can I upgrade somehow without uninstalling my current version completely?

Any insight into this is appreciated as well as recommendations as to what repo I should register from where I can get 5.5.9.

BR,
Henry

Comment: Not sure if it is a case but maybe will help http://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version

Comment: That's not an upgrade, that's a downgrade

Comment: So that's embarrassing... ehrm, I mean of course it's a downgrade. Alright, maybe now it will be easier to find a solution to my problem ha, ha.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant, PHP 5.5.38 is newer than 5.5.9.
this is a minor version update look into the PHP release notes for that version.